# Calculating $\sum_{n=1}^k n^p(n+1)^a$, with $a\neq p$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I know $\sum_{n=1}^k n^p$, thanks to the [Faulhaber’s formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula), which is $k^{p+1}/(p+1) + O(k^p)$. Similarly, it is possible to know $\sum_{n=1}^k(n+1)^a$.

My question is

> How can I calculate the following, with $a\neq p$?
> $$\sum_{n=1}^k n^p(n+1)^a$$

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: From Prasun’s comment, we can use the binomial theorem for $(n+1)^a$ and then plug it back in the questioned sum and reuse Faulhaber’s formula for the $\sum_{n=1}^k$ $\sum_{m=0}^a {a \choose m} n^{m+p}$

Comment: Please include the sums you know, within the post.  Also, use the first person singular: this is your question you've been assigned; it is not "our question".  You can ask for help, and meet us half way, but "we" won't do all of one's work for anyone.

Comment: I wasn’t assigned this question, I’m trying to explore something about Confluent Vandermonde matrices and in my process, I reached this point, and having a little clue about it could be helpful. And I’m new here so please calm down.

Comment: It's not the point whether you were assigned the question or not.  The point is, it is *your* question, so use the first person singular when asking.  We will help those who meet us halfway without expecting us to do their work for them.  So please calm down and read more about how to ask a good question, rather than blaming users trying to clue you in.

Comment: [How to ask a good question on math.se](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|126.2429).

Comment: If $a,p$ are non-negative integers, you can simply expand $(n+1)^a$ using binomial theorem and then use Faulhaber's formula for each of the individual sums.

Comment: Yes you’re definitely right! Thanks for the idea!